# Append the name of the file with awk

Tags: formatting, gawk

Using gawk for Windows included in GnuWin32, how do you append the filename to a text file?.

This is an example of what I want:

```
Filename -> text.txt
"aaaa","bbbb","c"
```

The result should be:

```
"aaaa","bbbb","c","text.txt"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It exists (at least in Linux version) a variable `FILENAME` with the name of the file in process. So use it:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ",";
    }
    {
        print $0 OFS "\"" FILENAME "\""
    }
' input-file
```

Comment: I tried this one liner, but it doesnt work awk "{print $0 FILENAME}" < input.csv > output.csv. In the output it appends a -, is the syntax right? or this means that in the windows version I don't have the FILENAME variable. Thank you!

Comment: @Eduardo: Use `awk '...' input.csv >output.csv` without the input redirection.

Comment: When you redirect stdin, awk is no longer reading from a file but from stdin. In that case, `FILENAME` is `-`

Comment: I cant believe that was the error, I was stuck with that changing the syntax, looking at examples, getting crazy with the print function, and it was just the redirection. Thanks a lot!